# XQuery Update Facility

Tags: xquery, xquery-update

I have got a quick question regarding XQuery update, Dose XQJ support implementing `XQuery update facility` to insert an element into an XML document?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the XQuery Processor and XQJ implementation you are working with. As an example, [BaseX](http://basex.org) and Charles Foster's [implementation](http://xqj.net/basex/) of XQJ is one combination that in fact supports the XQuery Update Facility.

Answer (score 0):

Zorba also supports XQJ and XQuery update. You can find out more at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/entry/2012/07/27/XQJ_From_Zorba